# (code=exited, status=150) on apache asp.net core

Tags: c#, linux, apache, asp.net-core

Im trying to host asp.net core app on linux ubuntu, and after configuring i get this error in service file:
Process: 4151 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/serije/Serije.dll (code=exited, status=150)
Main PID: 4151 (code=exited, status=150)

Jun 28 08:02:33 serv systemd[1]: app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=150/n/a
Jun 28 08:02:33 serv systemd[1]: app.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 28 08:02:33 serv systemd[1]: app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

my service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/serije
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/serije/Serije.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run app directly:
dotnet Serije.dll
(with correct paths)

Probably you'll get an error:
No framework found